# How to display an alert after checking the input from?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

What am I doing wrong ?

After checking the input form and clicking the "submit" button - if the link does not contain a value, then alert must be appeared.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="search-container">
    <form class="form-inline  input-group col-md-12 " method="post" name="searchForm" action="obtainSearchLink" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
      <input class="form-control" type="url" name="searchLink" placeholder="Search">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!--Alert must be here-->

  <div id="alert_placeholder"></div>
  <script>
    function validateForm() {
      var inputValue = document.forms["searchForm"]["searchLink"].value();
      if (!inputValue.indexOf("blablablah") >= 0) {
        $('#alert_placeholder').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>Search link is not valid!</div>')
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: why not just use ids and call using `$('#id').val()` ? you're already using jquery ..

Comment: you need to prevent the default action of your form otherwise it will still submit - so in your error if - return false after the error (as you return validateForm() on submit)

Comment: Your form button is not a submit button, so it's not triggering the form.
You also need to `return false` from the validateForm function to prevent the form from submitting
Finally, `!inputValue.indexOf("blablablah") >= 0` would be far better as `inputValue.indexOf("blablablah") === -1`